# How to share internet in Windows 7 using two netcards?

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, internet-connection

I have a Windows 7 system and two netcards. One is linked to the internet probider. The second one  connected to the router. How can I set up all this to allow my computer to work as router, allowing router to get an IP-address from my computer and internet access?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can think about doing this without conflict is to connect adapter 1 to adapter 2 and then have them both connected to the router, you can't physically turn your pc into a router.

A HUB can allow you to do this.

EDIT:

adding on from my own answer. Take a look at ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) a useful guide by Microsoft is here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing

Also take note from this support article, although it's for Windows XP it may still come to of some use.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126

Comment: There must be a way to turn my computer into router. It is all about corect configuring windows 7.

Comment: edited answer above